# How to change a logo to work on a similarly coloured background?

Tags: color, background, color-theory

This is my logo, which usually also has the company name below it:

[image]

It is mostly used on either a white or a purple background. I’d like to use the logo on some clothing, like purple t-shirts, but the colours of his cape blend together with the colour of the physical t-shirt.

Similarly, when the logo is used on a white background, the colour of his arms & body blend together with the background colour.

Putting the logo in a circle sort of works, but a white or purple circle doesn’t look right. I tried a sky blue but I don’t like it.

The other issue is I have a lot of different colours going on, ideally I could do with reducing this I think - but I’m not sure how.

How could I change my logo to work on purple and white backgrounds please?

Comment: Not sure I'd classify that as a "logo". But anyway, any relatively pastel color would work for a background.. grey, green, pinkish, orange, blue - even yes, purple. The trick is to use a lighter *value* than what is present in the image.

Comment: Do realise that none of the purple shades in this logo will print correctly: all of them are outside of the reach of CMYK.

Comment: @Vincent I have another version with different colour values for print 

Comment: Put a white border around your logo? But then your logo would be better by  not having so many colors and utilizing negative space as the linework, then you could in situations like this make the negative space white.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note**: Images in this answer are all *within the CMYK gamut*. Therefore the purple is not nearly as vibrant in this answer because CMYK *can not reproduce* that vibrant purple.

The *idea* behind branding is that the brand imagery does **not** change. One has to design around what is there, not change things to suit some specific usage.

If you want to redesign the color usage in the brand image to suit a purple background.... then change the purple in the figure to an orange or a more yellow color and it'll "pop" on a purple background. But... yellow/orange may not work well if there *isn't* a darker background.

Again, you *really* want to avoid altering the brand imagery.. so if you do decide to reconfigure color usage, whatever new configuration you settle on should be used *without a change* everywhere else the image is used. The *last* thing you want is a purple figure on A, then an orange figure on B, then a red figure on C, etc. Color consistency is *imperative* for branding.

---

The figure itself would work on just about any color **if** one uses a *different value*. Essentially, go with a more "pastel" color and the figure is seen without an issue.

[image]

Now, assuming you've *already* purchased purple shirts that essentially match the purple in the figure. It's possible to utilize a circle or some other background shape using any of the above colors to create some separation.

[image]

[image]

And, of course, there's always the possibility a simple colored stroke around the figure may be suitable...

[image]

Or a stroke and a shadow....

[image]

What you use and how you handle this is **highly** subjective. There is no "correct" way to configure everything. I'm merely offering a suggestion.

---

Sidebar: I *do* think the cape is far too long. He'd be tripping over it when walking. The cape should really end *before* his toes so he could stand without it dragging 3 feet behind him like a wedding dress. (And this is really more of a "mascot", not a "logo".)

Comment: Some really insightful comments Scott, thanks! Funnily enough I actually have him named as “mascot”. Often I’ll just use the company name and strapline below it, without the mascot (E.G. on email signatures). The idea to use a shape other than a circle is a really good one! I really screwed up the colour palette, I want to fix it for CMYK, update it everywhere, and then keep it unchanged - you’re absolutely spot on about branding! The cape is a great point too, I hadn’t even noticed that! Thanks again, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Here it is a man with patience to make examples of diferent options...

Comment: The outline is an excellent idea, I really like that - thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Only opinions:

On a purple background change the original purple of your shape to a little lighter:

[image]

Less colorful lighter purple can be printed on the full strength purple fabric as thin dithered white.

On a white background you can change the original shape to grayscale. Make the outline stroke a little thicker:

[image]

But preferably keep it colored, only let it have the outline stroke and make the purple to something less offensive, like this magenta. Then you at least have colors which can be printed on white as ordinary CMYK.

[image]

Better to check with the printer how small details can be printed and how to print white, orange and yellow on the bright purple. Or the bright purple on a white fabric. High resolution, non-transparent colors and overprints can be expensive.

It's possible that your website (Incrxxxxxx) with the strong purple appearance and the white character is already well known and you have a rapidly growing base of customers. In that case changing the purple should be avoided, as others have already said in the beginning. But it surely does its job also as shown in my 1st screenshot (the same bright purple fabric, lightened purple on the character, other character colors stay original). Printing it can be complex. The printer probably tells which exact versions of purple are actually achievable for the character clothing within his print processes.

Comment: I disagree with this entirely. Not sure why it is assumed the "purple shirt" has to be the same exact purple used in the character. A lighter, more pastel, purple shirt would work fine. One typically does *not* want to change colors of a mascot/branding.

Comment: @Scott The question was at least written "How to change a logo".  No claims about the thoughts of the questioner. The athletic mascot is still intact.

Comment: The thoughts of the questioner may be faulty, and that's what Scott pointed out he thinks is the case. The correct answer to 'How to change the logo' may be 'don't'.

Comment: The fabric material with the shown strong purple can well already exist  and it cannot be changed.  Printing something colored on it can be quite expensive. Double or quadruple it if the printed colors also must be as strong, but different.

Comment: I am open to changing the colours slightly. The t-shirts I’ve bought are a very similar colour to the logo. I’d update the logo everywhere else (online etc) to match, if its colours needed changing.

Comment: @DannyBeckett if you *already* have shirts.. and *no one here* knows what the shirt color actually is.. how can *anyone* answer effectively?

Comment: @Scott Apologies, code monkey here trying my hand at graphics  The shirts are basically exactly the same colour as my mid-purple, in hex it’s #6A00FF (I realise this is RGB). Essentially you could reword the question as “what can I do with this logo to make it work on an identical coloured background”. You raise a very good point though, perhaps grey t-shirts (for example) would work better. I’ve just picked up a heatpress, a vinyl cutter and some heat transfer vinyl I’ll be playing with tonight. I have way too many colours in this logo though  Thanks for your help! 

Comment: @oneprivate I like the slightly lighter purple in your 1st screenshot but the magenta one in your 3rd screenshot is quite different, not subtle

Comment: It assumed you want something colorful and also printable with low costs. Magenta can be colorful in CMYK print on white. Forget the magenta if your bright purple 6A00FF is already well known.